# Python - How to find an item exists in a list (or sublist)?

Tags: python, list, search, sublist

For example

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

I want to find if 7 is in `my_list`.? The answer should be True, because it is part of the last sublist. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems like a simple problem, if only one level of nesting.

Comment: It would be simple for one level, but what if the levels are arbitrary?

Comment: Yeah Anand, I what if without using additional space. I was trying to find out if there are any function that can find it out immediately without creating any other list or using extra space

Comment: Alex, yeah that's part of my question as well. I am looking for any simple and clean function to call to solve this problem without using extra space.

Answer (score 0):

If `mylist` was a list of only lists you could use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`

```
import itertools
mylist = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))
7 in merged
```

Since we have a list of ints mixed with lists, we define a custom filter.  This could also be done in a single list comprehension, but I can't figure that out right now.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,[5,6],[7,8]]
merged = []
map(lambda l: merged.extend(l) if isinstance(l, list) else merged.append(l), [i for i in mylist])
7 in merged
```

You could also use the deprecated `compiler.ast.flatten` function:

```
from compiler.ast import flatten
merged = flatten(mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if we cannot use extra space?